# Циклическая переадресация на сайте

Tags: php, битрикс, редирект

Пытаюсь реализовать следующее: при попадании на раздел `katalog` хочу чтобы сразу происходила переадресация на страницу `apteki`.
Для этого написал следующий код:

```
if($APPLICATION->GetCurDir() == "/katalog/") {
    LocalRedirect("/katalog/apteki.php");
}
```

Но после нажатия появляется сообщение

> На этой странице обнаружена циклическая переадресация

Как исправить?

Answer (score 5):

Условие срабатывает всегда, поскольку у вас каталог остается одним и тем же.

Нужна смена подхода:

```
if($APPLICATION->GetCurPage() === '/katalog/index.php') {
    LocalRedirect("/katalog/apteki.php");
}
```

[`CMain:GetCurPage()`](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cmain/getcurpage.php)

> Возвращает путь к текущей странице относительно корня. Нестатический
>   метод.
>
> Если файл текущей страницы явно не определён, то определение
>   индексного файла каталога будет проходить по алгоритму представленному
>   в описании функции [`GetDirIndex`](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/functions/file/getdirindex.php).